# Two tables join two results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a two tables one with blog news and another with articles. Simply what i need to do is join them so i have code like this

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('blogs')
          ->select('blogs.id as BlogId....')
      ->join('articles', 'articles.highlight = 1', 'left')
      ->join('authors', 'articles.author = authors.id', 'left')
      ->join('companies', 'authors.company_id = companies.id')
      ->get();
```

Join is working ok but then i need to do echo for data in foreach and here my problem comes. I have duplicated blogs under articles. So if i have 5articles under every is blog post(i have only one). Is there any possible way to show only one blog and then articles?

Thanks

Comment: post the tables so we can think what is appropriate code

Comment: What you want to do needs to be done in several queries, you will NOT be able to get 1 blog then all the related articles in the same query without repetition. I would suggest getting the blog then doing another query to get each of the related articles.

Answer (score 0):

Most people will tell you to foreach over your outer table, but that is terrible. Try using the Underscore library http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/#groupBy on your result array, as I show here:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/08/no-more-machine-gunning-use-underscore-php